# Need to create objects with member variables value, but cannot use constructor with parameters, also cannot use setter methods for member variables

Tags: java, constructor

I am creating a new library in which I have a class(UserResponse) with 6 String variables, we have set of 3 constructors with parameters using which we are currently creating objects.The first version of lib is successfully running, for the 2nd version of lib I am asked to remove all the constructors of UserResponse class, but there are some classes which are using parameterized constructor to create objects. I cannot create object using default cons and use setter to set values. Is there any better way to create object with parameters initialized.

```
    public class UserResponse{
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
    private String s3;
    private String s4;
    private String s5;
    private String s6;


    //getters and setters

    //Parameterized Constructors

    }

class SomeService{

public UserResponse someMethod(){
//business logic

return new UserResponse(value1, value2, value3);
}
}
```

Comment: *I am asked to remove all the constructors of UserResponse class*: Why? Why don't you ask the person asking you to do that and imposing these apparently arbitrary constraints to explain you why, and how to deal with them?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand, on the 2nd version you want to re-write your library or it will new edition which hasn't relation with 1st edition? If it hasn't so you can create your own parametrised constructor like in the first version. And why you can't create an object with def constr? You can add `UserResponse(){}` into your `UserResponse` class and after that you'll be able to use setters with def constr. Also, you can create static fields. But as I said, I don't clearly understand what you want)

Comment: It will be second version of library, not rewriting the library. I already tried to create new object using default constructor and using setter method. But was asked not to go ahead with this approach.

Comment: Maybe you ask what approach is recommended. One other approach could be the builder-pattern.

Comment: Note that the term "parameterized" generally refer to generics. I see no trace of generics here, so I assume that you mean "constructors with parameters".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your class utilization manner it has been designed for.

1. If the class' clients must have the ability to construct the `response` freely, with arbitrary fields set - `builder` pattern would serve the need. This approach is used, for example, in Atlassian Confluence Model API, look at [Content](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/5.9.8/com/atlassian/confluence/api/model/content/Content.html)'s builder() method. You cannot construct `Content` directly (all constructors are private) or mutate it (no setters), so you *build* it like this:

```java
Content.builder()
    .space(currentSpace)
    .parent(parentPage)
    .title(titleToUse)
    .type(ContentType.PAGE)
    .body(bodyToUse, ContentRepresentation.STORAGE)
    .build()
```

Builder is internal and have access to all fields.

2. If there are a limited amount of use cases for the class construction, then  `factory`-based idea fits better:

```
Content::Factory::buildResponseForUseCase1(/* use case specific parameters set*/)
Content::Factory::buildResponseForUseCase2(/* list of parameters dictated by use case 2 */)
```